# Array in C returns strange numbers, different output after every run

Tags: arrays, c, output

I am trying to create a program that takes a list of articles (CitationList) and their citations and saves them into another, more organized list. The new list (Library) saves an entry for each article and keeps an array of its citations.

Every time I print the new list (Library) I get a return of strange numbers, for example here is the output of the first 6 lines:

```
Article: 87005,
Citated Articles: 87013,
Citated Articles: -2013178764,
Article: 87124,
Citated Articles: 99007,
Citated Articles: 99011,
```

And here the output after running again:

```
Article: 87005,
Citated Articles: 87013,
Citated Articles: -2013178764,
Article: 87124,
Citated Articles: 99007,
Citated Articles: -2013166909,
```

The -2013.... numbers are appearing out of nowhere. The other 5 digit numbers are all always correct. Here are three methods that might be responsible. I'm new to C, so please try to be patient with me, I really don't know what this could all be caused by!

**Here a minimal, reproducible example:**

citation.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "citation.h"

CitationList *newCitationList ()
{
  CitationList *cl = (CitationList *) malloc (sizeof (CitationList));
  cl->count = 0;
  cl->allocated = 10;
  cl->citations = (Citation **) calloc (cl->allocated, sizeof (Citation *));
  return cl;
}


Citation *newCitation (CitationList *cl)
{
  if (cl->count >= cl->allocated)
  { cl->allocated *= 2;
    cl->citations = (Citation **) realloc (cl->citations, cl->allocated * sizeof (Citation *));
  }
  Citation *c = (Citation *) malloc (sizeof (Citation));
  cl->citations[cl->count++] = c;
  return c;
}

void readCitationList (CitationList *cl, char *fileName)
{
  FILE *file = fopen (fileName, "r"); //r stands for read
  if (file == NULL)  { perror (fileName);  exit (1); }
  int r, citatingArticle;
  do
  {
    r = fscanf (file, "%d", &citatingArticle);
    if (r != EOF)
    {
      Citation *c = newCitation (cl);
      c->citatingArticle = citatingArticle;
      r = fscanf (file, "%d", &c->citatedArticle);
    }
  }
  while (r != EOF);
  fclose (file);
}



Library *newLibrary ()
{
  Library *lib = (Library *) malloc (sizeof (Library));
  lib->count = 0;
  lib->allocated = 10;
  lib->articles = (Article **) calloc (lib->allocated, sizeof (Article *));
  return lib;
}



Article *newArticle (Library *lib)
{
  if (lib->count >= lib->allocated)
  { lib->allocated *= 2;
    lib->articles = (Article **) realloc (lib->articles, lib->allocated * sizeof (Article *));
  }
  Article *a = (Article *) malloc (sizeof (Article));
  a->count = 0;
  lib->articles[lib->count++] = a;
  return a;
}

/**Create a list of citating articles without duplicates**/
void fillLibrary (Library *lib, CitationList *cl){
  int lastCitatingArticle = 0;
  int currentCitatingArticle = 0;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < cl->count; i ++){
    currentCitatingArticle = cl->citations[i]->citatingArticle;
    if (!(currentCitatingArticle == lastCitatingArticle)){ //remove duplicate articles
      Article *a = newArticle(lib);
      a->articleId = currentCitatingArticle;
      lastCitatingArticle = currentCitatingArticle; //move on to next article in list
      fillBibliography(a, cl);
    }

  }

}
//Fill an array of citations and add them to the article
void fillBibliography(Article *a, CitationList * cl){
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < cl->count; i ++){
  if (cl->citations[i]->citatingArticle == a->articleId){
         a->bibliography[a->count] = cl->citations[i]->citatedArticle;
         a->count++;
  }
 }
}

void printLibrary (Library *lib)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < lib->count; i ++){
    printf ("Article: %d, \n", lib->articles[i]->articleId);
    for(int j = 0; j < lib->articles[i]->count; j ++){
      if (lib->articles[i]->bibliography[j] != 0){
        printf ("Citated Articles: %d, \n", lib->articles[i]->bibliography[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

citation.h

```
#ifndef CITATION_H
#define CITATION_H


typedef struct
{
  int citatingArticle;
  int citatedArticle;
} Citation;

typedef struct
{
  Citation **citations;
  int count;
  int allocated;
} CitationList;

typedef struct
{
  int articleId;
  int count;
  int bibliography[];
} Article;

typedef struct
{
  Article **articles;
  int count;
  int allocated;
} Library;


Citation *newCitation (CitationList *cl);
CitationList *newCitationList ();
void readCitationList (CitationList *cl, char *fileName);
Library *newLibrary ();
Article *newArticle (Library *lib);
void fillLibrary (Library *lib, CitationList *cl);
void fillBibliography(Article *a, CitationList * cl);
void printLibrary(Library *lib);



#endif // CITATION_H
```

main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "citation.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char *fileNameCitation;

  /**Get file name from **/
  if (argc < 2)
  { fputs ("usage: programm <citationfile>\n", stderr);
    exit (1);
  }
  else{
    fileNameCitation = argv[1];
  }

  CitationList *cl = newCitationList ();
  readCitationList (cl, fileNameCitation);
  Library *lib = newLibrary ();
  fillLibrary (lib, cl);
  printLibrary(lib);


  return 0;
}
```

Input citation.dat file:

```
87005 87013
87005 87156
87124 99007
87124 99011
87098 87124
87098 99011
```

Comment: then you have either an unitialzed structure element, or an array index that is out of bounds.  Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  Please also edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: Without debugging your code, there are several possibilities: You are accessing uninitialized variable, you have some out of bounds access, you have an integer overflow somewhere.

Comment: This smells of *undefined behaviour* and I would like to quickly copy/paste and compile this to see what warnings might be given - but that's not possible. Normally it would take just a few seconds.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run to reproduce the problem, preferably as a single code block, and the example input you used.

Comment: `Article` has a flexible array member. Where do you specify its size when creating an article with `newArticle()`?

Comment: Just to underline @Barmar above. We can see that `fillBibliography()` makes some assumptions about what `newArticle()` does that if incorrect will lead to the unpredictable behaviour described. It needs to initialise count to 0 and allocate sufficient memory for the flexible member.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the help so far! I have included my code so that it can be copy and pasted to try out. Thanks so much!

Comment: `r = fscanf (file, "%d", &citingArticle); if (r != EOF)` is not really sufficient.  If `scanf` returns 0, then citingArticle has not been written to.  Since it was uninitialized, later attempts to access that value are undefined.

Comment: @Barmar I think you got me going on the right track! I did not define an array size. Having defined it now, it works like a charm! Thank you so much and thanks to everyone else as well. I'lll take your comments to heart on my learning journey!

Comment: If `bibliography` can be variable length, it should be a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: I see! Great to know that arrays can by dynamic, I'll look into that